# Python : appened the value of created_date based on the condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-slicing

i am trying to write one function which will create a new column called `last_created_date`, and appened the value in that column as per condition.

so this is the data.

| rounded_geo_lat | rounded_geo_lng | created_date | distance_1_lat_lng | distance_2_lat_lng | distance_3_lat_lng | distance_4_lat_lng | distance_5_lat_lng | last_created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26.11 | 74.26 | 16-01-2024 11:29 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | null |
| 25.77 | 73.66 | 16-01-2024 12:29 | 70.91359357 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 16-01-2024 13:29 |
| 25.23 | 73.23 | 16-01-2024 13:29 | 142.2333872 | 0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 16-01-2024 15:20 |
| 24.67 | 72.94 | 16-01-2024 14:29 | 207.8935555 | 142.1494871 | 0 | NaN | NaN | 16-01-2024 15:43 |
| 24.41 | 72.65 | 16-01-2024 15:20 | 248.8830913 | 182.2445736 | 0 | 0 | NaN | 16-01-2024 15:43 |
| 24.41 | 72.65 | 16-01-2024 15:43 | 248.8830913 | 182.2445736 | 108.3518041 | 4.1 | 0 |  |
| 24.21 | 72.27 | 16-01-2024 17:28 | 291.1047773 | 222.9644721 | 149.2166506 | 84.94979054 | 44.46789779 |  |

so over here i want to derive `last created date` column per rake.
every pair of `rounded_geo_lat, rounded_geo_lng pair` corrospondes to `distance column` first pair will have `distance_1_lat_lng`, 2nd pair will have `distance_2_lat_lng`, 3rd pair will have `distance_3_lat_lng` and so on..

note: when we iterating distance column corrosponding to lat,lng pair we always will exclude self value in distance column and will go down till last value of that rake device.

now ,
case 1: while iterating down thorugh distnace column, there is no value less then `5 (<5)` then last_created_Date will be `null`. (look at distance_1_lat_lng) and break the loop else continue

case 2: while iterating down thorugh distnace column from current pair of lat,lng when there is only ONE value less then 0.1 (<0.1) (look at distance_2_lat_lng) then pick up the created_date for that corrosponding value and add it to the last created date column. and break the loop else continue

case 3: while iterating down thorugh distnace column from current pair of lat,lng when there is multiple value less then 0.1 (<0.1) (look at distance_3_lat_lng) then pick up the created date of last occuring value and put it in last_Created_Date for that pair of lat_lng and break the loop else continue

case 4: while iterating down thorugh distnace column from current pair of lat,lng when there is value in the column which is > 0.1 and < 5 then put the created date of first occurence of that value as last_Created_Date.

i have written this function but while writing this above condition it is not giving expected result.

```
def find_and_append_created_dates(df_0):
    df_0["last_created_dates"] = None  # Add the new column with initial values of None
    
    # Iterate over unique rake devices
    for rake_device in df_0['rake_device'].unique():
        rake_device_df = df_0[df_0['rake_device'] == rake_device]
        
        # Iterate over distance columns for the current rake device
        for i in range(len(rake_device_df)):
            distance_column = f"distance_{i+1}_lat_lng"
            
            # Iterate over rows below the current row
            for j in range(i + 1, len(rake_device_df)):
                distance = rake_device_df[distance_column].iloc[j]
            # Iterate over distance columns
            for distance_column in rake_device_df.filter(like='distance_').columns:
                # Iterate downward from the row after the current row
                has_value_less_than_5 = False
                for j in range(i + 1, len(rake_device_df)):
                    distance = rake_device_df[distance_column].iloc[j]

                    if pd.isna(distance):
                        continue

                    # Condition 1: No value less than 5 in the entire column
                    if distance < 5:
                        has_value_less_than_5 = True  # Mark that a value less than 5 exists

                    # Condition 2: First occurrence of value less than 0.1
                    if distance < 0.1 and not found_date:
                        found_date = rake_device_df.loc[rake_device_df.index[j], "created_date"]
                        break  # Stop iterating if you find a value less than 0.1

                # If no value less than 5 was found, assign NULL and break the loop
                if not has_value_less_than_5:
                    found_date = None
                    break

            # Assign the found_date (or None if not found) to the last_created_dates column
            df.at[rake_device_df.index[i], "last_created_dates"] = found_date

    return df
find_and_append_created_dates(df)
print(df)
```

Column last_created_date in the table i gave u is the expected output, we want to derive that column only, based on table above

Comment: Please add the expected output

Comment: @gtomer Column last_created_date in the table i gave u is the expected output, we want to derive that column only, based on table i gave